# INDEX MATCH to return multiple results based on date range and name criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dashboard

I'm trying to create a dashboard to return multiple results based on a name and date range criteria. The date range is Start date to End date. I tried using ***INDEX/MATCH*** code as below:

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$12,MATCH(1,(($C$3:$C$12=$H$2)*($B$3:$B$12>=$H$3)*($B$3:$B$12<=$H$4)),0))
```

but I was only able to display the results for a set of data.
I want to display more than 1 result for the specific name and date range.
For example as in the picture, the result for Client name Albert should show 2 results for the specific date range and name, but I was only able to return 1 result.
I want to populate the cells with all the results for that specific date range and name.
How do I do this?

***My working excel file.***
[image]

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ***Microsoft-365*** then use `FILTER()` function like-

```
=FILTER(A3:D10,(C3:C10=H2)*(B3:B10>=H3)*(B3:B10<=H4),"No Record Found")
```

For older version of excel you can use `AGGREGATE()` function. See second screenshot.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$D$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($3:$10)-ROW($2:$2))/(($C$3:$C$10=$H$2)*($B$3:$B$10>=$H$3)*($B$3:$B$10<=$H$4)),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

***Screenshot of FILTER function.***
[image]

***Screenshot of Aggregate function.***
[image]